# NEMA 6-20R amperage

Tags: wiring

I have some mining hardware and it's been running on 120v outlet for like 1.5 years and it works but the power wires are always warm and I've had to replace several that have burnt out, no fire or sparks because I monitor them daily. I'd like to have them plugged into a 240v outlet as the power supply works on either and will only draw half the amps as right now (11.5A on 120v 15A breaker, on 240v it should be about 5.8A) so it should in my mind run the wires cooler and therefore safer.

So I want to install a NEMA 6-20R like this one on a 25A breaker with 10 awg wire
[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000U39UY4/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_awdb_imm_Z1BQG1CCCRYGSYJ078KE?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000U39UY4)

I know the 20 in 6-20 is 20 amps so does that mean I can plug in 2 miners that draw 1300w each and be good?

Also is it allowed to run these in line with each other? Like if I install 2 next to each other in a box can I run one off of the other to power 3 devices in total. If so what wire gauge and breaker is needed?
Or do I need to install a new breaker and new wires for each outlet? Because I only have space in my breaker box for one 240v breaker, so I'm trying to figure out how to power 3 miners off that one breaker position.[image][image]

Comment: You mention in a comment to an answer that this is a rental. What city/state/country/etc. are you in? Some jurisdictions require licensed electricians for work done in a rental situation.

Answer (score 1):

That panel is already populated with many double-stuff breakers, so no loving there for making more room.  Unless you are willing to replace the entire main panel with one that has more spaces, your best bit (A little IT slang there!), would be to install a sub-panel. Feed it from the last remaining 240 v space with a capacity appropriate for your bitcoin miners and lots of reserve. Go big. Follow all the rules for a sub-panel (isolated neutral from ground, etc.).  Then you can run your miners at 120 or 240 from the sub-panel.

Comment: A sub panel is not an option what about installing this breaker?  https://www.amazon.com/Eaton-BR420-Circuit-Breaker-4-Pole/dp/B008CRC6SM the box may be full but most of the stuff isn't in use and on a normal day there is only about 75A being pulled from the main lines.

Comment: I won't comment bc I'm just not sure and don't want to give bad advice. Others will probably chime in regarding certain breakers being rated for certain panels and I just don't have enough expertise on that.  You may have a good solution, but I can't confirm that.

Comment: NRTL Listing is typically brand specific, Eaton BR breakers are not listed for Siemens. Eaton makes "CLxx" breakers Classified to work in Siemens panels, but not in that configuration.

Comment: Without seeing the original panel cover I wouldn't be able to guess if a Siemens Q22020CT2 can be mounted in your panel.

Comment: I have an eaton breaker lying around and it fits and seems to work fine. It's only a single pole 15a so I'd just as much figure any eaton would work in there.

Comment: @rasmukri -- don't use an Eaton BR in there! I suspect your panel is a Siemens, but can you get us photos of the labeling on the inside of the door please?

Comment: The inside door is blank and if I pull off the cover it is blank on the back as well the only label is the one I posted already. Since all the breakers in there are siemens I'd assume the panel is the same brand

Comment: @rasmukri -- not an unreasonable assumption.  However, is there any labeling on the inside left or the inside right of the panel cabinet?

Comment: No, just pulled it off to check, the only label is the one I posted.

Comment: Eaton BR breakers will snap in (with the wrong insertion force), grip the bus stab all wrong, arc, catch fire and burn up your deposit (and the bus stab too).

Answer (score 0):

It must be a 20A breaker, 12 AWG or larger wire. Can't use a 25A breaker. You can put as many 6-20 receptacles on the circuit as you want, as long as you don't exceed 20A total. However, your actual usage for continuous loads should be 80% = 16 A. 3 x 5.8, if that's the real constant load, it's almost 18A.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was afraid of. Added a pic of my breaker box, is there any way I can get 2 more 240v breakers to fit in there?

Comment: There are *some* panels that can take a quad, where the inner pair and the outer pair are each 240V. Whether or not you can do that depends on the particular panel. Can you upload a picture showing the label/diagram, usually on the inside of the front cover?

Comment: Added another pic, that is the only label in my box and it doesn't say anything I find useful, but this shit is from like the 70's or 80's

Comment: A subpanel may be your best bet. That is an awfully small panel.

Comment: Can't do a sub panel what about the breaker I posted in the other guys answer? I didn't even know quad breakers were a thing but it seems like it would solve my issue

Comment: The breaker in the other answer is the right kind of breaker in concept. But the specifics (a) depend on matching your actual panel (which that one probably doesn't - based on codes on other breakers - but a Q22020CT2 *might*) and (b) your breaker being able to handle that many circuits - some panels are rated for "every space can be doubled", some are definitely not. FYI, 70s or 80s ain't so old.

Comment: @rasmukri -- what prevents you from doing a subpanel?

Comment: Can't do a sub panel because it's a rental. Owners are cool with modding what is in place and adding circuits provided it's up to code in doing any additional wiring or anything. But no new panel or anything like that.

Comment: Then you absolutely **must** find out the actual panel specifications, because putting in the wrong breaker will get both you *and* the owners in trouble if anything goes wrong.

Comment: Well how do I find the specs for the panel when there is no label anywhere and the owners aren't the original for the house? What about using this breaker with some 6-15 outlets? https://www.homedepot.com/p/Siemens-2-15-Amp-Double-Pole-Type-QT-Quad-Circuit-Breaker-Q21515CT2/206632148

Comment: @rasmukri  By the way, 6-15 receps are allowed on 240V/20A circuits as long as there's 2 or more sockets (in the whole circuit)... it's the same rule that allows 120V/15A receps plural on 20A circuits.  Also that breaker is correct, and they make a 20A version of it, as well as a 20/25 and a 20/30. So you could hang 20A circuits on the outside of the existing 25A and 30A circuits also.